# Show imageview when url is loading - WebView

Tags: android, webview, imageview

How do i show imageview                                                                            when a URL is loading in Webview and Disappear when page has loaded?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="90dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `WebViewClient` and implements `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` methods , here example  display how to use them

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-webview-with-progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

first set the Visibilty of the imageVIew to show :

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

then you have to do the following :

```
webVIew.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

and use the onPageFinished to set the Visibility of the imageVIew to Gone .

and please give me feedback

Hope That Helps .

Comment: can you complete the code please? the visibility part

Answer (score 0):

In  activty layout add webview and image.

set Web view visiblity=gone initaly.

```
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
        {


            //Make the image disappear after URL is loaded/.

                if(progress == 100){
                  imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  webVIew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
          }
     });
```

Comment: gone initaly ki hunda aa?

Comment: <WebView
     android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />